# Laravel Validate Checkbox Certain Value

Tags: laravel

I am simply needing to know how to validate my array of checkbox values to be in a certain list of values. So, I am using the "in:" validation rule as shown below, but it's returning the error that the value of the checked box is invalid. Do I need to do something different since it's an array of values sent via AJAX?

Controller:

```
if ($request->ajax())
{
    /*Create record in UserType Model with the values from the Type checkboxes*/

    $Type = Input::get('Type');

    $this->validate($request, [
        'Type' => 'required|in:A,B,C,D',
    ],[
        'required' => 'You must select at least one.',
    ]);

    foreach ($Type as $key => $value)
    {
        Auth::user()->userType()->create([
            'profile_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'type' => $value,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my form, I have the following inputs...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Type[]" value="A"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Type[]" value="B"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Type[]" value="C"/>
```

UPDATE:

So, I found in the Laravel documentation that you can validate arrays using * to get the key/values in an array. However, in my array it's just Type[] so I've tried the following with no luck.

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'type.*' => 'required|in:A,B,C,D'
    // or
    'type*' => 'required|in:A,B,C,D'
]);
```

Just not working. I know I need to retrieve the array value something with the `*`.

UPDATE:

I was running Laravel 5.1 when this option for validation is only available in Laravel 5.2. Solved.

Comment: Did you find a solution

Comment: Haven't had a chance to check. I will tonight and update this thread. However, I have done what you suggested and it didn't validate properly. It doesn't recognize that validation criteria and allows the form to be submitted.

Comment: And if you just use `required`? without `in`. And `Type`must be spelled exactly the same as in the form though (1. letter uppercase)

Comment: In the original question under the "Controller" section. That validation works with required, but throws an error with the "in" criteria. What happens there is that the validation is grabbing "Type", so the required criteria is fine (just need to check a box), but the "in" criteria needs the underlying value in the array so it thinks that my value isn't A,B,C,D.

Comment: I think I got it! forget the `required`

Comment: Well, complete oversight on my part. I'm running laravel 5.1 when this type of validation is available in 5.2. I need to upgrade and it'll work. Blahhhh. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oooh nooo! I was thinking "kind of spooky" ... Glad it works now

Comment: Would have been less a hassle if you added the `laravel 5.1` tag

Comment: Yeah that would have, however I was completely negligent on the version of Laravel I was running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**: The `required` isn't necessary when using `in` because it must be `A`, `B` or `C`. That is like a "*multiple*" required already.

**Second**: As shown in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays) just use:

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'Type.*' => 'in:A,B,C,D'
],[
    'in' => 'You must select at least one.',
]);
```

As your Input array is named `Type`. That would validate all Inputs named `Type`.

To be clear the asteriks could be replaced by e.g. `one` to just validate the Input named `Type[one]`:

```
'Type.one' => 'in:A,B,C,D'
```

or if the Input would be named `Type[one][name]`

```
'Type.one.name' => 'in:A,B,C,D'
```

Comment: So, to test it out, I changed the validation to 'Type.0' and it worked properly. Seems to be an issue when using the * specifically. I posted on Laracasts to see if anyone has other ideas. I'll post back here with any updates. Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: Solved by updating to Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
    if($this->has('Type') && is_array($this->get('Type'))){

        foreach($this->get('Type') as $key => $Type){

            $rules['Type'.$key.'] = 'required|in:A,B,C,D';
        }
```

Comment: Not working. I found something in to documentation, but I'm having trouble implementing it. It's the "Validating Arrays" Portion. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Use this 

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'type.*' => 'required|in:A,B,C,D'
    // or
    'type*' => 'required|in:A,B,C,D',
]);

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 ..

```
        $this->validate($request, [
        'Type' => 'required|array'
    ]);
```

Worked for me for checkboxes